# combining column variables with same values into a new variable

Tags: r, merge, cbind

dataset being used is in this google sheets link 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eV33Sgx_UVtk2vDtNBc4Yqs_kQoeffY0oj5gSCq9rCs/edit?usp=sharing

```
AMC.dataset$ExamMC.A<-surveySP15$Exams_A
AMC.dataset$ExamMC.A<-factor(NA, levels=c("TRUE", "FALSE"))
AMC.dataset$ExamMC.A[AMC.dataset$Exams_A=="1 time"|AMC.dataset$Exams_A=="2-4 times"|AMC.dataset$Exams_A==">4 times"]<-"TRUE"
AMC.dataset$ExamMC.A[AMC.dataset$Exams_A=="0 times"]<-"FALSE"
AMC.dataset$ExamMC.A=as.logical(AMC.dataset$ExamMC.A)
```

I use these 5 lines of code to re-code all 9 of the Exams_A through Exams_I variables into logical binary outcomes of "True" for those who have answered 1 or more times for any of these 9 variables. I would like to combine all of these variables into a new column in the dataset in which for each observation row, if there is even one case that is "true" for any of the 9 exams_A through I in that entire row, the new variable outcome will read as "true" meaning they have at least once committed any of te 9 types of Exam academic misconduct recorded in the dataset. if there are no true outcomes in the observation row i would like the new variable outcome to read as "false" meaning that they (the observation row) has never committed Exam academic misconduct

what I have for this new variable's code is

```
 AMC.dataset$ExamMC = any(AMC.dataset$ExamMC.A, AMC.dataset$ExamMC.B, AMC.dataset$ExamMC.C, AMC.dataset$ExamMC.D, AMC.dataset$ExamMC.E, AMC.dataset$ExamMC.F, AMC.dataset$ExamMC.G, AMC.dataset$ExamMC.H, AMC.dataset$ExamMC.I)
```

however this code has been overridden by the last variable output in the string (AMC.dataset$ExamMC.I), which has 215 False cases and 0 true, will override the rest of the string to give the new variables output of 215 "false" cases even though other variables may hold "True" as their case output.

EDIT

I have now created a data frame for the set of exam misconduct variables

```
AMC.dataset$ExamMCdf<-data.frame(AMC.dataset$ExamMC.A, AMC.dataset$ExamMC.B, AMC.dataset$ExamMC.C, AMC.dataset$ExamMC.D, AMC.dataset$ExamMC.E, AMC.dataset$ExamMC.F, AMC.dataset$ExamMC.G, AMC.dataset$ExamMC.H, AMC.dataset$ExamMC.I)
```

now my question is how to go about creating a composite variable in a new column that correctly reads through each observation row, labeling any row that has even a single "true" outcome in the data frame as "true" for the composite variable. Any observation row with no "true" outcomes should be labeled as "false" by the composite variable.

Thanks for all of your help.

Comment: I guess this would sort of be like an ifelse statement, so that the new composite variable will read "true" if that observation row has recorded "true" for any of the 9 types exam misconduct recorded in the dataset, if else (as in if there are no "true" outputs for any of the 9 types of academic misconduct) then the new composite variable will read "false" as in that observation row has not committed any type of exam misconduct..

Comment: or perhaps as a merge function?

Comment: that spreadsheet is not shared publically or to those with link access

Comment: fixed the problem with the link! please let me know if there's anything else i can provide to make answering my question easier

Comment: is this a simulated data set? you probably aren't allowed to share this data if this is actual students and you're in the US (due to FERPA)

Comment: yes this data set is simulated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a composite row that checks for any TRUE values in the other data frame columns, use the `any()` function wrapped in `apply()` to go row by row. I think you can apply it to your situation:

```
#Makes a dataframe with TRUE/FALSE values and a low chance for TRUE
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(
  Exams_A = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), 10, TRUE, c(.1, .9)),
  Exams_B = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), 10, TRUE, c(.1, .9)),
  Exams_C = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), 10, TRUE, c(.1, .9)),
  Exams_D = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), 10, TRUE, c(.1, .9)),
  Exams_E = rep(TRUE,10) # Inserts row of all TRUE's to show that you can limit scope
)

data$ExamMC <- apply(data[, 1:4], 1, function(x) any(x))
data$ExamMC <- apply(data[, 1:4], 1, any) # This is the updated version
                          # ^ This part sets what columns you want to search
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I found this to be very helpful to me so i appreciate your help. both answers gave me a better understanding for R in general

Comment: i'm having trouble finding the right use for the function(x) part of that last line of code, is there a page where i can read up on the use of function(x)?

Comment: I actually just ran the code without the `function(x)` part and it works _as long as you remove the `(x)` from `any`_. I updated the code to show this. You can look at `?apply` for more information but my understanding is if you are passing something to the function you call with `apply()` or want to make your own function that receives the row as data to process, you need to add in the `function(x) ...` bit.

Comment: okay, so i took out the (x) part for the any(), and im getting feedback that looks like this:

    [[1]]
    function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("any")

    [[2]]
    function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("any")

    [[3]]
    function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("any")

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're after, but here's how I would do what I think you've got in mind:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(surveySP15)

exams <- paste0("Exams_", LETTERS[1:9])
surveySP15[ , paste0(exams, "_binary") :=
             lapply(.SD, function(x) x %in% c("1 time", "2-4 times", ">4 times")),
           .SDcols = exams]
```

This will create a variable for each exam (e.g., `Exams_A_binary`) which is (`logical`) `TRUE` if it's coded in the data as 1 or more time and `FALSE` otherwise. Here's the relevant output:

```
> surveySP15[ , paste0(exams, "_binary"), with = FALSE]
     Exams_A_binary Exams_B_binary Exams_C_binary Exams_D_binary Exams_E_binary Exams_F_binary Exams_G_binary
  1:          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE
  2:          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE
  3:          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE
  4:          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE
  5:          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE
 ---                                                                                                         
223:          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE
224:           TRUE           TRUE           TRUE          FALSE           TRUE          FALSE          FALSE
225:          FALSE           TRUE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE
226:          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE
227:          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE          FALSE
     Exams_H_binary Exams_I_binary
  1:          FALSE          FALSE
  2:          FALSE          FALSE
  3:          FALSE          FALSE
  4:          FALSE          FALSE
  5:          FALSE          FALSE
 ---                              
223:          FALSE          FALSE
224:          FALSE          FALSE
225:          FALSE          FALSE
226:          FALSE          FALSE
227:          FALSE          FALSE
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! this really helps my understanding of where i went wrong. I appreciate the help!